# How to POST data into DB using Tastypie API

Tags: api, tastypie

Can I perform create/delete operation directly calling API URI? Something like

```
http://www.somedomain.com/api/entry/?action=create&book_title=something&year=1986&author=someone
```

rather then passing header in curl?

I can do this with CURL:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name": "me", "passwd": "123456"}' http://www.somedomain.com/api/entry/
```

But i want this action by requesting the url in browser rather then using curl.
Is this possible in tastypie?

Comment: Your question seems to be "How to GET data into DB using Tastypie API"  since you want to use a plain url.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `dispatch` method on your `Resources`

```
from tastypie import resources

class MyResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        # TODO stuff here

    def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
        action = request.GET.get("action")
        if action in ["POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"] and request.method == "GET":
            request.method = action
            request.POST = request.GET
        return super(MyResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)
```

Then you can call your api staright from the url with `GET`:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/api/entry/?action=POST&book_title=something&year=1986&author=someone
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, i have solved it in my way. BTW you have taught me an alternative way which will be useful for the next project.

Answer (score 0):

GET puts arguments in the URL, POST requests should put their data in the message body

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29